# Is this an Excel bug? Chart with large number of rows and columns includes data values as part of chart legend

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

**In summary**

I have a line chart with 25 series. If I chart the first 100 rows of data, all is well. If I chart 200 rows of data, the legend labels start including data values.

**Details**

In the screenshots below I have obfuscated the label text by placing blue rectangles over them (except you can still see the first letter in each case).

In this screenshot, the legend looks as I would expect it to be -

[image]

However in this screenshot, the legend starts including data values -

[image]

The only difference is that I increased the chart's source range from 100 rows to 200 rows per the last 3 digits circled in red in the screenshot below.

[image]

For what it's worth, I actually want to chart about 10,000 rows...